# Length of lines python reads from stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem why this code. Why does the string length not match with my input?

```
input: a 
output: 2

from sys import stdin
for line in stdin:
  print(len(line))
```

Comment: because it includes line termination char. Try `len(line.rstrip())`. You'll have the same behaviour on a regular file

Comment: yes, also try : `print(repr(line))` to reveal all...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : That's an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like any file-like iterator, `stdin` yields lines with linefeeds/newlines when iterated upon. Which explains you get an extra char when counting.

You could use `rstrip("\n")` to make the count right (remove right hand newline):

```
from sys import stdin
for line in stdin:
  print(len(line.rstrip("\n")))
```

(note that substracting 1 to the result also works)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it also contains your linefeed character '\n'

try this code :

```
from sys import stdin
for line in stdin:
    for x in line:
        print(x)
```